# Not able to see staticContext in props of react component during server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I am serverside rendering an app and the server code looks like this

```
const markup = renderToString(
<StaticRouter context={{a:1}} location={req.url}>
<App d='8' />
</StaticRouter>
)
```

and in the App component I am printing out props

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
console.log(this)
}
```

but the output does not have staticContext, it looks like this

```
App {
props: { d: '8' },
context: undefined,
refs: {},
updater:
 { isMounted: [Function: isMounted],
 enqueueForceUpdate: [Function: enqueueForceUpdate],
 enqueueReplaceState: [Function: enqueueReplaceState],
 enqueueSetState: [Function: enqueueSetState] } }
```

I am using react 16.3 and react-router-dom 4.3.1, why am I not able to access the staticContext prop?

Comment: Have you resolved it?